# How to add notification system in chat app using socket.io.?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, notifications

I have integrated Chat feature in my MERN application. Which works fine,but there is no notification system for the chat feature. User does not know about new new message until he opens a chat manually.

To build a notification for my chat I am totally clueless. How would I generate a notification and send it to the user who has received a new message. And on reading a new message how that notification ends..

I have multiple users and I have stored their conversation in DB. Any guide or any material regarding this will be helpful for me..

Answer (score 0):

You need a Push notification service. There are many different APIs for sending push notifications in Android such OneSignal, Firebase Messaging Service (FCM).